# What do you call the publisher's logo on the title page and spine of a book?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a word for the publisher's logo at the bottom of the title page and on the spine of a book, but I can't recall it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be called "the Publisher's Logo." Perhaps you are referring to the material which describes who designed the book; the publisher's data; the materials used in its production [etc]. This is called "the colophon."

Added: "Publisher's Mark" is an alternative for "Logo"

Comment: +1 for knowing and telling what a colophon is. And is not! Thanks.

Comment: Chambers dictionary defines colophon as " publisher's imprint or emblem: formerly an inscription at the end of a book, often naming the author or scribe [...] as on a modern title page". So it would be fine here (at least in England),

Answer (score 0):

[Colophon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colophon_(publishing)): In publishing, a colophon is a brief statement containing information about the publication of a book such as the place of publication, the publisher, and the date of publication. A colophon may also be emblematic or pictorial in nature.