# What's the name of the section of a book authors use to describe technicalities?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't remember what this word is, but the usage is such that in this section authors will explain what font they used, what software they used and other technical things. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: [What do you call the publisher's logo on the title page and spine of a book?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/20081/5822)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Colophon](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colophon) fits the bill.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct.   In publishing, a colophon is a brief statement containing information about the publication of a book such as the place of publication, the publisher, and the date of publication. A colophon may also be emblematic or pictorial in nature.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colophon_(publishing)

Answer (score 0):

In magazine or periodicals "Mechanical Data" is where font, page size, column width, picture size etc is provided to potential advertisers or contributors.  I'm not sure if this is also used in book publishing, but it would probably work...